# Why is the Debug class static while the Trace class is not?

Tags: c#, .net

I noticed that

`System.Diagnostics.Debug` class is static: `public static class Debug`

whereas,

`System.Diagnostics.Trace` is not: `public sealed class Trace`

Both classes contain only static methods.

My understanding is that these classes have similar roles but are used within different environments, depending on the symbols defined.

So is there a reason for why one would be static and the other would not, when both of them only contain static methods?

Comment: `Trace` has constructor, but [not creatble...](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/diagnostics/Trace.cs,22) which is funny..

Comment: @Sinatr the constructor is private to make sure that you don't create an instance of the class, which would be pointless anyway since it has no non-static members. That's just good practice to prevent.

Comment: @fredrik, my comment was about comment. I know the purpose of `private` constructors, but one without references if confusing.. Maybe it was factory before refactoring something into a separate class? And someone just forgot to remove constructor and to make class static?

Comment: @Sinatr Ok, that wasn't clear. Though I think the reason behind it being private is pretty clear - the author wanted to make sure that it never has anything reference it.

Comment: It used to look the same as Trace, this changed was made at or after version 4.5.  Might have something to do with an integration from the corefx source tree, too hard to guess at this without having access to source control.  No practical difference.